# Cargo-cult programming: locking on System.Object

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

I think I've developed a cargo-cult programming habit:

Whenever I need to make a class threadsafe, such as a class that has a Dictionary or List (that is entirely encapsulated: never accessed directly and modified only by member methods of my class) I create two objects, like so:

```
public static class Recorder {

    private static readonly Object _devicesLock = new Object();
    private static readonly Dictionary<String,DeviceRecordings> _devices;

    static Recorder() {

        _devices = new Dictionary<String,DeviceRecordings>();

        WaveInCapabilities[] devices = AudioManager.GetInDevices();
        foreach(WaveInCapabilities device in devices) {

            _devices.Add( device.ProductName, new DeviceRecordings( device.ProductName ) );
        }
    }//cctor

    // For now, only support a single device.

    public static DeviceRecordings GetRecordings(String deviceName) {

        lock( _devicesLock ) {

            if( !_devices.ContainsKey( deviceName ) ) {

                return null;
            }

            return _devices[ deviceName ];
        }
    }//GetRecordings
}//class
```

In this case, I wrap all operations on `_devices` within a `lock( _devicesLock ) {` block. I'm beginning to wonder if this is necessary. Why don't I just lock on the dictionary directly?

Comment: This is normally necessary when you need to synchronize the initialization of the variable. Since this field is readonly you probably don't need the extra variable. That said, you haven't actually shown where you initialise `_devices`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your use case, locking the dictionary will be fine, since it is private. You still need to carefully design your class to prevent deadlocks.

If the dictionary is the only shared resource that needs thread safety and other parts of your code are thread-safe, I'd recommend using the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead of locking.

Comment: +1 - worth noting that if the dictionary is completely private and a simple lock will get the job done, it's much less complex than what occurs under the hood of `ConcurrentDictionary`. But if that functionality *is* needed, `ConcurrentDictionary` is a good choice.

Comment: Yes, I believe `ConcurrentDictionary` utilizes `CompareExchange` instead of `Monitor.Enter`. But as you say, the complexity is "under the hood" so at least it doesn't add _maintenance complexity_ to the code (in fact, it might reduce it a bit). Performance wise, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373.aspx) states that `ConcurrentDictionary` can be significantly faster in case of high frequency reads/writes on multicore systems; however, `Dictionary` will be faster by comparison in single threaded read/writes (in which case you wouldn't need locking).

Comment: Agreed, the maintenance complexity will outweigh any loss of performance in almost any case. Interesting MSDN read.

Comment: I've amended my question to show how I was using the `_devicesLock` object.

Answer (score 2):

It is not needed if you are sure that the main object is used completely within the class. Strictly speaking it is not necessary even if it is but version with 2 variable is much easier to reason about:

- whoever reads code does not need to think about if the main object is ever exposed and potentially locked by something outised your class
- the code with separate object for locking looks more in line with good practice
- will be safer if one accidentally/intentionally exposes the main object